# How are counted calls per day in Facebook Graph API.

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, limit

After reading the facebook policies about thresholds:
https://developers.facebook.com/policy/#features
"If you exceed, or plan to exceed, any of the following thresholds please contact us by creating a confidential bug report with the "threshold policy" tag as you may be subject to additional terms: (>5M MAU) or (>100M API calls per day) or (>50M impressions per day)."

I would like to understand better if calls per day are considered "http requests" or requests per item.

If I make a call with concatenated ids does it count for the items requested?
Ex:
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=123456,456789

Is it considered 1 call or 2 calls from the facebook platform?

Answer (score 1):

You can batch your request and make them all in only one, the maximun requests per batch is 50, you can find more information here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/